# Fast reading of unicode files in windows in R

Tags: r, data.table

I always use `fread` from **data.table** package to read in large tables. But apparently it does not support reading unicode files in Windows (Windows 7 Professional to be more precise)

Here is the file I tried to read:

```
A,B
ą,ž
ū,į
ų,ė
š,ę
```

It works fine if I read it in Mac OS X, or I read it with `read.csv` with option `encoding=UTF-8`. Unfortunately `fread` does not have this [option](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/563).

So are there other fast ways to read unicode tables in Windows, or I should just use other OS? Or am I missing something obvious?

Here is the output of `sessionInfo():`

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45   plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.5    reshape2_1.4.1 stringr_0.6.2
```

**Update:** Pasting the output as requested.

```
> aa<-fread("F:/R/unicode_test2.csv",verbose=TRUE)

Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.000000 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Positioned on line 1 after skip or autostart
This line is the autostart and not blank so searching up for the last non-blank ... line 1
Detecting sep ... ','
Detected 2 columns. Longest stretch was from line 1 to line 5
Starting data input on line 1 (either column names or first row of data). First 10 characters: Ä„,B
All the fields on line 1 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
Count of eol: 5 (including 1 at the end)
Count of sep: 4
nrow = MIN( nsep [4] / ncol [2] -1, neol [5] - nblank [1] ) = 4
Type codes (   first 5 rows): 44
Type codes: 44 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 44 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 2 column slots (2 - 0 dropped)
Read 4 rows. Exactly what was estimated and allocated up front
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map (rerun may be quicker)
   0.000s (  0%) sep and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Count rows (wc -l)
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection (first, middle and last 5 rows)
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation of 4x2 result (xMB) in RAM
   0.000s (  0%) Reading data
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation for type bumps (if any), including gc time if triggered
   0.000s (  0%) Coercing data already read in type bumps (if any)
   0.000s (  0%) Changing na.strings to NA
   0.001s        Total

> aa
   Ä„  B
1: Ä… Å¾
2: Å« Ä¯
3: Å³ Ä—
4: Å¡ Ä™
> aa$A
[1] "Ä…" "Å«" "Å³" "Å¡"
> aa$B
[1] "Å¾" "Ä¯" "Ä—" "Ä™"

> bb <- read.csv("F:/R/unicode_test.csv",encoding="UTF-8",strings=FALSE)
> bb
  A B
1 a ž
2 u i
3 u e
4 š e
> bb$B
[1] "ž" "į" "ė" "ę"
> bb$A
[1] "ą" "ū" "ų" "š"
```

Comment: @Arun, nice to hear.

Comment: Could you please test it as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Arun, sorry it does not work with the new version.

Comment: Could you paste the output when run with `verbose=TRUE`?

Comment: Nevermind, I can reproduce the issue now.. not sure what happened the last time.

Comment: One last Q. What do you get for `Sys.getlocale()` on your Mac?

Comment: It is a Unicode locale:  `"fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8"`

Comment: The file is read succesfully in locale `en_US.UTF-8` in Debian also.

Comment: It reads the first column of 2nd and 3rd row as "U". Otherwise, everything else reads fine, and I'm on same locale as your Windows 7 locale.. Strange.. I'll write back if I manage to find something. Thanks again.